# "System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument" message appears when navigate webbrowser

Tags: c#, navigation, browser

when I try to set a specific html data stored in string into webbrowser, this message appears instead of html content

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument
```

my code is : note that **html code stored in temp_data**

```
this.main_webpage.Navigate("about:blank");
HtmlDocument d_c = main_webpage.Document;
d_c.Write(temp_data);

main_webpage.DocumentText = d_c.ToString();
main_webpage.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ToString` is the one inherited from `Object`, which returns the *type* of the object. `HtmlDocument` doesn't override it.

Use the `Body` property of `HtmlDocument` - it returns the body element:

```
main_webpage.DocumentText = d_c.Body.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: good, but the problem that your way remove all css code and change the original html code .. I can not understand why ?

Comment: The `Body` property represents the document `body` tag. This will not include anything within and including the `header` (which would be linked CSS files). Also, `HtmlDocument` _parses_ the HTML and creates an internal representation - this is what you see.